# If I subtract 1 from the n,n entry of a Pascal Matrix, why does the determinant become zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

In [problem 19.2](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/determinant-formulas-and-cofactors/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.6sol.pdf), how did the author reach this statement: "Since the n, n entry multiplies its cofactor positively, the overall determinant drops by 1 to become 0."

I was able to solve it a different way, but I feel that my approach was less efficient. I'd like to understand the solution's approach.
Here is what I did:

$det(\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&2&3&4\\1&3&6&10\\1&4&10&19\end{bmatrix}) = det(\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&2&3&4\\1&3&6&10\\1&4&10&20\end{bmatrix}) - det(\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&2&3&4\\1&3&6&10\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix})$.

and

$ det(\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&2&3&4\\1&3&6&10\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}) = (-1)^3 * det(\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&2&3&4\\1&3&6&10\end{bmatrix}) = (-1)^3 * (-1) * det(\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&2&3\\1&3&6\end{bmatrix})$.

therefore

$det(\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&2&3&4\\1&3&6&10\\1&4&10&19\end{bmatrix}) = 1 - 1 = 0 $.

It feels like the solution skipped doing this step, I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 3 & 6 & 10 \\ 
1 & 4 & 10 & 19 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Compare

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 3 & 6 & 10 \\ 
1 & 4 & 10 & 20 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

five by five

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 \\ 
1 & 4 & 10 & 20 & 35 \\ 
1 & 5 & 15 & 35 & 69 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 \\ 
1 & 4 & 10 & 20 & 35 \\ 
1 & 5 & 15 & 35 & 70 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: I understand it algebraically and thanks for this answer, but why was the Pascal matrix orthogonally diagonalized? I get that since the last eigenvalue was set to 0, then det(A) = 0. But Gilbert Strang's MIT Course gets to diagonalization a few lectures later... There must be an alternative explanation that was being referenced...

Comment: Still doesn't explain the "Since the n,n entry multiplies its cofactor positively, the overall determinant drops by 1 to become 0". 

Where is the the cofactor being multiplied?

Comment: This is very nice, but this is probably not what Strang had in mind.

Comment: @N.T: This is not diagonalization, let alone orthogonal diagonalization. This is LPU-decomposition, at best (except that P is singular here). And it isn't unmotivated here, as I bet Strang used something similar to compute the determinant of the (original) Pascal matrix.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Hi. Horn and Johnson call this congruence diagonalization. I found that many of the students were mixing up attempting $P^{-1} A P = D$ with $P^T H P = D$ for symmetric real $H.$ This version is good for Sylvester's Law of Inertia.  Evidently this is taught in some countries, not so much in the U.S. I put a full discussion at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Comment: @WillJagy: Right, it's *congruence* diagonalization, the kind that is normally used for quadratic forms rather than matrices. But it's not necessary to know the general theory of congruence diagonalization to come up with these matrices here, and I suspect that Strang already showed the way for the original Pascal matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make this more general:

> **Proposition 1.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $A = \left(a_{i,j}\right)_{1\leq i\leq n, \  1\leq j\leq n}$ be an $n \times n$-matrix over a commutative ring $\mathbb{K}$. For each $u, v \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$, we let $A_{\sim u, \sim v}$ be the $\left(n-1\right)\times\left(n-1\right)$-matrix obtained from $A$ by removing the $u$-th row and the $v$-th column.
>
> Let $p \in \mathbb{K}$. Let $B = \left(b_{i,j}\right)_{1\leq i\leq n, \  1\leq j\leq n}$ be the $n \times n$-matrix obtained from $A$ by subtracting $p$ from its $\left(n,n\right)$-th entry. (That is, each entry $b_{i,j}$ of $B$ equals the corresponding entry $a_{i,j}$ of $A$, except for the $\left(n,n\right)$-th entry $b_{n,n}$ of $B$, which is $a_{n,n} - p$ instead.)
>
> Then, $\det B = \det A - p \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim n}\right)$.

Proposition 1 tells you how the determinant of a matrix changes when you modify a single entry. This entry is the $\left(n,n\right)$-th entry in the case of Proposition 1, but you can similarly analyze any other entry (except that you need an extra $\left(-1\right)^{i+j}$ sign in the formula if you modify the $\left(i,j\right)$-th entry).

How would this help you with your question? Well, if $A$ is your original Pascal matrix of size $n$ (whose $\left(i,j\right)$-th entry is $\dbinom{i+j-2}{i-1}$ for all $i,j \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$), and if $p=1$, then the $B$ in Proposition 1 is precisely the modified Pascal matrix whose determinant you are looking for. Proposition 1 yields $\det B = \det A - \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim n}\right)$ (since $p = 1$), but both $\det A$ and $\det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim n}\right)$ equal $1$ (because both $A$ and $A_{\sim n, \sim n}$ are Pascal matrices, and you know that those have determinant $1$), so this becomes $\det B = 1-1 = 0$ as you want to show.

It remains to prove Proposition 1:

*Proof of Proposition 1.* From $b_{n,n} = a_{n,n} - p$, we obtain $b_{n,n} - a_{n,n} = -p$.

Recall that the matrix $B$ differs from $A$ only in its $\left(n,n\right)$-th entry. Thus,
\begin{equation}
B_{\sim n, \sim j} = A_{\sim n, \sim j}
\qquad \text{ for each } j \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}
\label{darij.1}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
(since the matrices $B_{\sim n, \sim j}$ and $A_{\sim n, \sim j}$ are obtained from $B$ and $A$ in the same way, and this way does not depend on the $\left(n,n\right)$-th entries of $B$ and $A$).

Also,
\begin{equation}
b_{n,j} = a_{n,j}
\qquad \text{ for each } j \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\right\}
\label{darij.2}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
(for the same reason).

Expanding the determinant of $B = \left(b_{i,j}\right)_{1\leq i\leq n, \  1\leq j\leq n}$ along the $n$-th row, we obtain
\begin{align}
\det B
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \left(-1\right)^{n+j} b_{n,j} \det\left(\underbrace{B_{\sim n, \sim j}}_{\substack{= A_{\sim n, \sim j} \\ \text{(by \eqref{darij.1})}}}\right) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \left(-1\right)^{n+j} b_{n,j} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim j}\right) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \left(-1\right)^{n+j} \underbrace{b_{n,j}}_{\substack{= a_{n,j} \\ \text{(by \eqref{darij.2})}}} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim j}\right) + \underbrace{\left(-1\right)^{n+n}}_{=1} b_{n,n} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim n}\right) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \left(-1\right)^{n+j} a_{n,j} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim j}\right) + b_{n,n} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim n}\right) .
\end{align}

On the other hand, expanding the determinant of $A = \left(a_{i,j}\right)_{1\leq i\leq n, \  1\leq j\leq n}$ along the $n$-th row, we obtain
\begin{align}
\det A
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \left(-1\right)^{n+j} a_{n,j} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim j}\right) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \left(-1\right)^{n+j} a_{n,j} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim j}\right) + \underbrace{\left(-1\right)^{n+n}}_{=1} a_{n,n} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim n}\right) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \left(-1\right)^{n+j} a_{n,j} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim j}\right) + a_{n,n} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim n}\right) .
\end{align}

Subtracting the last two equalities from each other, we obtain
\begin{align}
& \det B - \det A  \\
& = \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \left(-1\right)^{n+j} a_{n,j} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim j}\right) + b_{n,n} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim n}\right) \right) \\
& \qquad - \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \left(-1\right)^{n+j} a_{n,j} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim j}\right) + a_{n,n} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim n}\right) \right) \\
& = b_{n,n} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim n}\right) - a_{n,n} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim n}\right) \\
& = \underbrace{\left(b_{n,n} - a_{n,n}\right)}_{= -p} \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim n}\right) \\
& = -p \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim n}\right) .
\end{align}
Thus, $\det B = \det A - p \det\left(A_{\sim n, \sim n}\right)$. This proves Proposition 1. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

Note: I don't have enough reputation to comment so I will try to make my point with your equations.

Your approach seems to be more efficient than the answers here to be honest. As I understand you only need to show the determinant below is equal to 1.

$
det(\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&2&3&4\\1&3&6&10\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix})=1
$

Since all pascal matrices has a determinant of 1 this includes:

$
det(\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&2&3\\1&3&6\end{bmatrix})=1
$

Thus the first equation can be shown easily. I think this is as intuitive and efficient as it gets.